# Can not catch event in the second click

Tags: java, javafx

Hj. I have a combobox in Javafx. 
Initially, I am in AVAILABLE. Then I press the combobox to choose 'AUXUALY' state, it will pop up a dialog to confirm 'AUXUALY' or not. The issue happens when I cancel the pop-up, I can not catch event click to 'AUXUALY' in the next click.

Looking to the attached image, it seems we are still in 'AUXUALY' state because I can see a rectangle covering the 'AUXUALY' button. I can catch event only if I select the LOGOUT state.

Is there anyone here suggest me to overcome this problem?

[image: states]

```
class MyCombobox extends Combox{

 this.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {  // can not catch event here after canceling the dialog 
if change = 'AVAILABLE' then 
if change = 'AUXUALY'  then PopUp.getinstance().showDialog();
if change = 'LOGOUT' then 
}
}

class PopUp extends Window{

btOk.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
...
}
btCancel.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
hide();
}
public void showDialog(){
this.show();
}
}
```

Comment: We need to see the code. It would be best if you could create a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which only shows your problem and does nothing else so we can run it ourselves. Use the *edit* link under your question to add the code to your question.

Comment: i just update my question

Comment: It should be code that **compiles** and **runs** and shows the problem you have.